# Can I create a survey by google docs from a Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need create a survey with google API using javascript. Is it posible?

Answer (score 1):

Using Apps script you can use FormsApp to create and edit your forms and use them as a survey.
here are the links to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

http://www.google.com/forms/about/